# MySQL COUNT(DISTINCT) giving wrong values with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains custom user analytics data. I was able to pull the number of unique users with a query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS 'unique_users'
FROM `events`
WHERE client_id = 123
```

And this will return `16728`

This table also has a column of type `DATETIME` that I would like to group the counts by. However, if I add a `GROUP BY` to the end of it, everything groups properly it seems except the totals don't match. My new query is this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) AS 'unique_users', DATE(server_stamp) AS 'date'
FROM `events`
WHERE client_id = 123
GROUP BY DATE(server_stamp)
```

Now I get the following values:

```
|-----------------------------|
| unique_users  | date        |
|---------------|-------------|
| 2650          | 2019-08-26  |
| 3486          | 2019-08-27  |
| 3475          | 2019-08-28  |
| 3631          | 2019-08-29  |
| 3492          | 2019-08-30  |
|-----------------------------|
```

Totaling to `16734`. I tried using a sub query to get the distinct users then count and group in the main query but no luck there. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is further information to help diagnosis.

Comment: Those two query conditions are different. Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Apologies. I copied that last one from a test I was running. I have corrected this.

Comment: As far as sample data, I am unsure of the best way to display it. My table currently has over 30,000 rows in it, and made up of 22 columns but only a couple of the columns are relevant to this. The `user_id` column is an integer that points to users in a different table. The `server_stamp` column is of type `DATETIME`.

Comment: An user who is connected with events on multiple days (e.g. session starts before midnight and ends afterwards) will occur the number of these days times in the new query.

Comment: @Islingre This thought had occurred to me and I will have to check to verify but I generated random user data to populate my table so it should be only one log per user. However, after 30,000 random generations duplication is possible I suppose. I will touch back after verifying. Is it safe to say that there is nothing immediately wrong with my use of `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Assuming every user is only associated with events on one day.. yeah, the query should be right and your expectation about the sum should be true

Comment: @Islingre You were absolutely correct. Removing the `DISTINCT` from the first query yielded the total from the second query. Thank you very much. If you would like to post an answer about how using `GROUP BY` can cause duplications even when using `DISTINCT` I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Remember, you're welcome to answer (and accept) your own question on SO.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. Just wanted to give you a chance to get the credit. I will write an answer here shortly when I'm in front of my laptop. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the chance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user, who is connected with events on multiple days (e.g. session starts before midnight and ends afterwards), will occur the number of these days times in the new query. This is due to the fact, that the first query performs the `DISTINCT` over all rows at once while the second just removes duplicates inside each groups. Identical values in different groups will stay untouched.

So if you have a combination of `DISTINCT` in the select clause and a `GROUP BY`, the `GROUP BY` will be executed before the `DISTINCT`. Thus without any restrictions you cannot assume, that the `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` of the first query and the sum over the `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` of all groups is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Xandor is absolutely correct. If a user logged on 2 different days, There is no way your 2nd query can remove them. If you need data grouped by date, You can try below query -

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) AS 'unique_users', DATE(MIN_DATE) AS 'date'
FROM (SELECT user_id, MIN(DATE(server_stamp)) MIN_DATE   --  Might be MAX
      FROM `events`'
      WHERE client_id = 123
      GROUP BY user_id) X
GROUP BY DATE(server_stamp);
```