How to group by and COUNT DISTINCT for each individual column
I have a query like this
SELECT 
    SiteId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
              CASE 
                  WHEN 
                      CreatedReceiveLeve1 >= '2024-01-01' 
                      AND CreatedReceiveLeve1 <= '2024-10-01'
                     THEN CodeProfile
              END) AS TotalRecords
FROM
    LogTTHC
WHERE
    SiteId IN (60, 249)
GROUP BY
    SiteId;

My purpose is to count DISTINCT TotalRecords for each site.
The problem is that the clauses
WHERE SiteId IN (60, 249)

and
WHERE SiteId IN (249)

will return different values.
In reality, I need to query for many SiteId and many Metrics to show. What is the suitable query to do that?

Sample data and expected results would be ideal, it's not clear why the two clauses would show different results for row SitreId=249, given that you are grouping by SiteId. Also what is Metrics? Furthermore why is the CASE WHEN inside the aggregation and not in the WHERE.

@Charlieface The reason for why the two clauses would show different results is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57860302/22761301. Other Metrics is something else I want query like: http://surl.li/yiebaw

Not sure how that's relevant other than to show that if you have a GROUP BY then each grouping is calculated separately, which should have been obvious. Like I said, some sample data and expected results (as text not images) would help immensely in understanding what your issue is.

What is the result in the two cases and why is it a problem?

You could use COUNT(your_expression) OVER (PARTITION BY SiteId) if you want to select many more columns that wouldn't be in your grouping.
So to extend a bit, your query would look something like:
SELECT
    ISomeColumn,
    SomeOtherColumn,
    COUNT(your_expression) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupColumn)
FROM 
    SomeTable


Please try this:
SELECT 
        SiteId,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        LogTTHC
    WHERE
        SiteId IN (60, 249)
    and CreatedReceiveLeve1 >= '2024-01-01' 
    AND CreatedReceiveLeve1 <= '2024-10-01'
    GROUP BY
    SiteId;


Could you share SHOW CREATE TABLE default.LogTTHC FORMAT Vertical?
for ClickHouse SQL dialect better use uniqExact and If aggregation combinator
look detail in https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators
and
https://clickhouse.com/blog/aggregate-functions-combinators-in-clickhouse-for-arrays-maps-and-states
COUNT(DISTINCT + CASE shall be the same with uniqExactIf
but it depends on count_distinct_implementation setting
check
SELECT * FROM system.settings WHERE name='count_distinct_implementation' FORMAT Vertical
could you compare
SELECT 
    SiteId,
    uniqExact(CodeProfile) AS totalUniqProfiles,
    uniqExactIf(CodeProfile, CreatedReceiveLeve1 >= '2024-01-01' AND CreatedReceiveLeve1 <= '2024-10-01') AS uniqProfilesForDateRange
FROM
    LogTTHC
WHERE
    SiteId IN (60, 249)
GROUP BY
    SiteId;

and
SELECT 
    SiteId,
    uniqExact(CodeProfile) AS totalUniqProfiles,
    uniqExactIf(CodeProfile, CreatedReceiveLeve1 >= '2024-01-01' AND CreatedReceiveLeve1 <= '2024-10-01') AS uniqProfilesForDateRange
FROM
    LogTTHC
WHERE
    SiteId IN (249)
GROUP BY
    SiteId;

is this queries contains different result for SiteId=249?

There is the SHOW CREATE TABLE default.LogTTHC FORMAT Vertical and the result of 2 query https://codeshare.io/3yzV64

The query you provide not work as expect

your table have ReplacingMergeTree replace FROM     LogTTHC to FROM LogTTHC FINAL and check results again

still got that problem, decide to use the for loop in code instead of GROUP BY. My api is too slow but the query result was ok
